# How to add a node in front of boost property_tree

Tags: c++, boost

I have a xml

```
<MyXML>
    <Tag2>2</Tag2>
    <Tag3>3</Tag2>
    <Tag4>4</Tag3>
</MyXML>
```

and read it into boost::property_tree::ptree xmlroot using boost::property_tree::read_xml

Now if I add a new node by

```
xmlroot.add("MyXML.Tag1", "1");
```

This new node will add to back of existing tags. After boost::property_tree::write_xml, I get

```
<MyXML>
    <Tag2>2</Tag2>
    <Tag3>3</Tag2>
    <Tag4>4</Tag3>
    <Tag1>1</Tag1>
</MyXML>
```

Is there a way to insert new node in front of Tag2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it's outside of scope of standard accessors like `get` and `add` so one has to go the longer and more cumbersome way of iterators. Basically you need to get an iterator for your node and use `insert` or `push_front` insert a new node at required place.

Full example.:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::string xml_content =
"<MyXML> \
    <Tag2>2</Tag2> \
    <Tag3>3</Tag2> \
    <Tag4>4</Tag3> \
</MyXML>";
        std::stringstream xml (xml_content);
        pt::ptree tree;
        pt::read_xml (xml, tree);
        /* ~~~~ KEY STUFF ~~~~ */
        auto root = tree.find("MyXML");
        root->second.push_front({"NewTag", decltype(tree)("1")});
        /* ~~~~ KEY STUFF ~~~~ */
        pt::write_xml (std::cout, tree);
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Key stuff explained:

```
    auto root = tree.find("MyXML");
    root->second.push_front({"NewTag", decltype(tree)("1")});
```

Ok, so 1st line is a no brainer, we need to get our "work" node.

Second line uses [`push_front`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#idp76194656-bb), which inserts a new node at the front of the caller. But out caller is at the `second` field of the iterator, which is the result of `find("MyXML")`.

Then `push_front` expects a pair of key and `self_type`. I used brace initialization for pair, and a string literal for key. Creating a new node of matching type is a little bit more tricky, since the constructor using value is marked as explicit. So, one has to use it's type. I got it using `decltype` of the `tree`.

If anything can be simplified I happily welcome all improvements.

Comment: I use root->second.push_front(pt::ptree::value_type("NewTag", "1")); in 2nd line of key stuff. It also works

Comment: Yea, I wanted to skip explicit types. It's another way to invoke explicit constructor.